# How to retrieve a variable from object to update it in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model Score, which has q-id's as columns.
Ex:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,default = False )
    q1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=8)
    q2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=8)
    .
    .
    q100 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=8)
```

Now I want to access the value of q (q1 to q100) and update the value.

```
def ballot_update(request,group_id,q_id):
group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=group_id)
if request.POST:
    vote = request.POST.get('vote')
    q_id = 'q'+ q_id
    score = Score.objects.get(pk=vote)
    newscore = 10 + score.q_id
    s_update = Score.objects.filter(pk=vote).update(**{q_id:newscore})
return ballot_home(request,group_id)
```

I am getting the error 'Score' object has no attribute 'q_id'

Attached is the snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T0Xa.png [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should change your model:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,default = False )

class Qs(models.Model):
    score = models.ForeignKey(Score)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    q_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=8)
```

Then you do not have 100 q_is in your model. And you can easily access the q-values.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getattr()` to get the object's attribute by name:

```
newscore = 10 + getattr(score, q_id)
```

Comment: What should i do if i want to use order_by(q_id) ?
Ex:  Score.objects.filter(group_id=group).order_by(q_id).reverse()

Comment: You should do just as you wrote: `order_by(q_id)`.  The `order_by()` method takes a simple string as it's argument.